# Поиск по шаблону в mysql

Tags: mysql, база-данных, sql

Как выглядит запрос к БД в поиске Гугла или ВК. Когда через AJAX выводятся все возможные результаты.

У меня в таблице есть поля name, surname. Важно сделать, что-бы когда пользователь например вводил имя саша и не заметил, что у него регистр другой(саша - cfif) то  поиск нормально бы работал и выдавал запросы на имя саша

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как оно у гугла не знаю) Но я бы сделал так:

```
WHERE (`name` LIKE '%саша%' OR `name` LIKE '%cfif%')
```

Comment: Павел "LIKE '%cfif%'" будет искать в БД cfif, а если ты cfif напишешь например в ВК, то оно выдаст поиск по запросу Саша, там как-то слово переводится в другую раскладку. Может в БД event.keyCode записывается ?

Comment: У вас клавиатура перед глазами, посмотрите какие клавиши в Русской раскладке, соответствуют каким клавишам в английской. Далее, получив запрос от пользователя, перегоняйте его из одной раскладки в другую и ищите по таблице оба варианта, один который пришел от пользователя и второй который получился после вашей обработки, какой нибудь из них будет правильный.

Comment: а разве по keyCode не быстрее будет? И как должна выглядеть функция для перевода в другую раскладку